# is there anyway to put the reference of map likes this?

Tags: python

I tried to work this code out but I am stuck in this point.
Here is the [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I0C9.jpg) that I am attaching of the problem scenario.

```
import math


def calculateDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
    return dist

l_array = []
while True:
    input_string = input("Enter trip map references: ")
    if not input_string:
        exit()
    l_array = input_string.split()
    print(l_array)
    array_length = len(l_array)

    for i in range(array_length):
        if not (l_array[i].isupper()):
            print("bad reference", l_array[i])

    print(calculateDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2))
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting and show the entire code you have written so far?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zf3UF7pT

Comment: I am not able to continue with the code to get the output like how it is in image,please help

Comment: Can you help me with the example how C2,B5 and Y25 gives a total distance of 16.8KM

Comment: Welcome to SO!... Please share your thoughts and add them to your questions. What obstacles are there at this point? Do you need help on your methods or on Python in general?

Comment: I am not able to produce output like it is in image, I am not able to understand how can I take the values from input line like A7 B3 C4 and calculate distance

Answer (score 0):

In this task you have severak subordinated tasks.

**Check the validity of the input**

There restrictions to the input that have to be fulfilled. In general it must consist of a series of coordinates separated by one space. Each coordinate must follow the pattern of one uppercase letter followed by an integer number.

```
A1 A2 R50
```

Any difference from these restrictions will abort the process and print out an error message.

**Transform the input**

As the input is not given in numerical form you have to convert it. A letter can be matched to its number in the alphabet, which leads to a numerical representation.

```
A := 1
B := 2
```

**Calculate the distance**

You already have it so far.

---

**Overall process**

One solution to the program as a whole can be seen in the following psedocode.

```
refs := input()  // Follows the pattern
dist := 0

if ( !checkRef(refs[0]) )
  return "ERROR"

ref0 := transformRef(refs[0])

for ref_i in refs[1:end]
  if ( !checkRef(ref) )
    return "ERROR"

  ref := transformRef(ref_i)
  dist += calcDist(ref0, ref)
  ref0 <- ref

return dist
```

---

**Python Hints**

You should read about the following.

- [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) -> Can split the whole input string
- [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) -> Returns the index in the ASCII representation of characters
- [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) -> Can convert strings consisting only of numbers into a numerical object